# An edge case in class String?

Tags: java, string, substring

Consider the following scenario:

```
String str = "str";
System.out.println("str subs: " + str.substring(3,3));
```

**Expected result:**
`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` (since beginIndex starts "after" the string ends)

**Actual result:**
The empty string is printed

From *String.java*:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
        new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

It's easy to see that the implementation doesn't take care of the edge case where:
`beginIndex == endIndex == count`  (`count` is the length of the string).

According to *[the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)* the method substring:

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.

It also states that the method throws:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex
>   is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is
>   larger than endIndex.

Does it *[makes sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)* to consider the case: `beginIndex == endIndex == count` as valid ? 

Am I missing something ?

Comment: It's certainly arguable, but I personally like this behavior. PHP's [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function returns `false` in this case and I found that to be an annoying edge case, where I was pulling data off some string buffer that became `false` once it was exactly emptied instead of `""`, and consequently broke a later `$buf === ""` check.

Comment: @Boann I didn't explore `substr`, and in Java this kind of behavior doesn't seem *arguable* to me (actually - I was looking for an argument that can explain this behavior and failed to find one - that's why I posted this question).

Comment: The substring `extends to the character at index endIndex - 1`. Why don't you expect an exception for `substring(0,0)`?

Comment: @Arian cause `string[0]` is not out of bounds.

Comment: For `endIndex = 0`, the last character to include is at `-1`, which is just as out of bounds as `startIndex = length`. Yet, you accept that `0,0` succeeds. It's the same for `3,3`, just from the other end of the string.

Comment: You didn't read the next sentence: `Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex` so when you accept `0,0` you accept a substring at length of `0` that starts at index `0`. This logic is not applied by any way to `substring(3,3)` in the example.

Comment: +4/-4 for the best question I asked so far. Nice! I wish someone who knows one of the implementers could either provide a solid explanation or open a bug...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"abc".substring(3,3) == ""
```

As you said, let's look at the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

okay

> The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.

The interpretation of this sentence is difficult regardless of the length of the string. But I think we can agree that an empty string does not violate this.

> Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

okay

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative

it is not

> or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object

it is not

> or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

it is not.

Behavior seems as promised to me.

You can also see it like this: the string `"abc"` contains four empty substrings, two between the characters, one at the beginning, and one at the end. They can be accessed via `substring` with `1,1` and `2,2`, `0,0`, and `3,3`, respectively. Compare also with the following code

```
class EmptyTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

         Matcher m = Pattern.compile("").matcher("abc");
         while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.start() + "," + m.end());
         }
    }
}
```

which prints

```
0,0
1,1
2,2
3,3
```

Comment: +1 for a nice detailed answer - you obviously investigated the docs carefully! Yet, the fact that index 3 is outOfBound is obvious (try to turn the string to char array and access the item at index `length`). For end-index that's fine cause according to the spec it is designed to be a right marker to the last item+1, but it is not, by any means, documented or detailed that begin-index can go out of bounds. The fact that Pattern matcher also goes "out of bounds" is a direct result of this bug...

Comment: Accessing the char at `3` would be somewhat equivalent to `substring(3,4)`, which fails too. The point is, `3,3` is an actual sub-string, so it should be accessible via `substring`, shouldn't it?

Comment: the letter `c` is at index 2, so I don't understand why do you consider [3,3] as an actual sub-string

Comment: `3,3` identifies the empty sub-string at the end of the string, *after* `c`, which is at index 2. Unless you would not agree that "abc" has *four* empty sub-strings.

Comment: I too thought that this is the most reasonable explanation, but, if the empty string "at the end" of the string is `[3,3]` - applying the same logic we should have been able to do `[-1,-1]` for the empty string at the beginning of the string. Since it makes no sense the "right" way to consider the first and last empty substrings are: `[0,0]` and `[2,2]`

Comment: I don't see by which logic `-1,-1` is the first empty string. And `2,2` cannot identify the sub-string at the end because it already identifies the sub-string between `b` and `c`.

Comment: @alfasin You should accept this answer, because it *is* the answer and it is correct. There is no "bug" here. The behavior you are witnessing is *exactly as it is documented to behave*. At no point is a promise *ever* made than an exception will be thrown if beginIndex > count. The documentation is clear and precise; your surprise at your observation merely indicates that you did not read it, not that there is a "bug".

Comment: @JasonC when a product design misses an important edge-case and as a result the product behaves in a way that doesn't make much sense - how would you call it ? I chose to call it a bug but if you have a better suggestion I'm willing to consider . Further, claiming I haven't read the docs  is a bit weird considering the quotes from the doc embedded in the question.

Comment: @JasonC BTW, I never wrote `beginIndex > count` - I wrote: `beginIndex == count` which makes me wonder how thoroughly have you read both the question as well as the answer...

Comment: @alfasin It was merely a typo. I meant >=. Not only does it make zero sense why you are so upset about this particular case, but the product design *didn't* miss an important edge case. They made a design decision on how to handle that case, and documented and implemented it. Arian's answer is correct no matter how much you would have personally liked the design decision to be different. The docs you quoted specifically allow the case you are complaining about; I didn't claim you didn't quote the docs, I claimed you didn't read (or understand) the docs you quoted.

Comment: @Jason C the docs don't "specifically" allow this case: the docs don't specify this case at all! And as I already wrote here in the comments: since the endIndex is defined to be the right marker+1 it makes sense for it to go 1 step out of bounds. That same logic does not apply to `beginIndex`

Comment: @alfasin The docs specify precisely what conditions cause that exception to be thrown. Are you saying that they don't? When the precise rules in the docs are applied to your specific condition, the behavior is precisely as expected. Why do you insist on being confused when the documented rules are very clearly being followed? If you insist on pretending otherwise, there's really not much more anybody can tell you. It's clear. It's documented. It's right there and it's no surprise. Did you *expect* an exception to be thrown for your case? Why? The rules are clear as day.

Comment: @JasonC "The docs specify precisely what conditions cause that exception to be thrown" - again, I'm not complaining about what the docs specify - I'm complaining against what the docs DON'T specify. The docs specify the behavior only when `beginIndex` is negative but it doesn't say anything about the case when it's outOfBounds on the right-side. You keep saying that the docs are precise: yes they are precise in regards to what they DO mention - but this is an undocumented behavior which is NOT mentioned nor implemented

Comment: and yes I do expect that `beginIndex == length` will throw an exception exactly like I would expect `array[length]` to throw an outOfBounds exception - wouldn't you ?

Comment: @alfasin So when documentation says "x happens if a > b", it confuses you when they don't also say "x does not happen if a <= b"? **The "if" in these types of contexts tends to actually mean "iff" (if and only if).** It would be rather redundant for them to say "if a and b then exception is thrown" then add "if not a and/or not b then exception is not thrown"... In exception documentation, at least in the JDK javadocs, you can generally expect that if the explicit conditions for throwing an exception are not met, the exception will not be thrown.

Comment: @alfasin As for your second comment, no I would not expect that. I would expect `.charAt(n)` to behave exactly like `[n]`, as they perform a similar function (although I would not be put off if they did not behave the same, as they are different APIs, as long as it was documented). I don't see a valid reason to assume `.substring(x, y)` would show the same behavior.

Comment: @alfasin Expanding on "iff" - it's similar to actual programming statements. If you wrote `if (beginIndex > endIndex) throw new Exception()`, the exception would not be thrown if that condition was not true. The convention in the documentation here is analogous to that logic. If another `if` statement after that could throw an exception in a different case, that corresponds to another bullet point condition in the documentation. **The documentation for `charAt(n)` does not explicitly specify that the exception is not thrown for `0 <= n < length`, why does that not similarly confuse you?**

Comment: I'll try for the last time and if you keep telling me that "that's what the docs says" I promise to give up on you :) From the docs: `IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.` Reading this, I'm under the impression that the writer tried to describe ALL the possibilities in one sentence. Now YOU ARE RIGHT that this case is included, but since it's not *specifically* described, and since **it's not a consistent behavior** - I tend to believe that the author simply missed it.

Comment: And by "a consistent behavior" I mean consistent with `chatAt(length)` and `array[length]`. I understand that since those are different APIs you're okay with it, so I guess there's no point to continue this discussion cause we're not agreeing on a basic thing such as expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`beginIndex == endIndex == count` means that the virtual "start cursor" would be placed right after the last character in the string, at the same point as the "end cursor", so you'd get a zero-length string. It seems just as valid as returning the empty string for `(0,0)`.

Comment: `beginIndex` starts after the string ends. That doesn't seem valid to me. A "substring" should be a *real* substring of the *string* (an empty string is a valid substring of any string). But here we try to "take" a substring from "outside" the string which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Further, if your claim would be valid, under the same logic we should get the empty string returned from a call with: `substring(length*2, length*2)`. If you were right that was an inconsistent behavior!

Comment: @alfasin Except that it *is* specifically prohibited to put the indices outside the string. I visualize this method as putting two slideable bounds somewhere in the slots between the character array, and both "before the first" and "after the last" are meaningful (though not always useful) positions. In particular, this means that loops can iterate through the string with more flexibility.

Comment: "after the last" makes sense only for `endIndex` which by definition is a right marker+1. It doesn't make sense to allow the left marker go `OutOfBounds`

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is consistent with:

```
String str = "str";
System.out.println("str subs: " + str.substring(2,2));
```

Also returns empty string and not a substring. Empty set is subset of all the sets.

Refer class java.lang.String
Parameters:
beginIndex the beginning index, inclusive.

Comment: According to your logic this behavior is *not* consistent with `str.substring(5,5)` (which throws an exception)

Comment: @harsh "up to" - yes, inclusive - no!

Comment: But in that case you are failing the validation to be within the bounds of the String. Would you accept it if the behaviour was to throw exception whenever start Index and End Index were equal? I wouldn't and I guess I am not alone.

Comment: @NitinDandriyal you're missing the point: I don't expect an exception to be thrown whenever start Index and End Index were equal, I expect an exception to be thrown when start Index is out of bounds (when start index points to `string[length]` it is no longer pointing to the string!).

Comment: Javadoc says beginidex is inclusive: param beginIndex the beginning index, inclusive.

Comment: @NitinDandriyal make no mistake: inclusive doesn't mean "out of bounds", it means: last (border) element included.